# How to abort running evaluation?

Tags: evaluation, button, interruption, abort

I would like to implement a "Stop" Button into a program that basically consists of a loop. 
Unfortunately I do not how to interrupt the running evaluation. 
Minimal Example:

```
Grid[{
{Button["Start", {i = 1; While[i < 10, Print[i]; Pause[1]; i++]}, 
Method -> "Queued"]},
{Button["Stop", {Quit[]}, Method -> "Queued"]}
}]
```

In this Case the "Stop" Button evaluates after the Evaluation from the "Start" Button has finished. Is there any possibility to quit the calculation immediately by a "Stop" Button?
Thanks in advance for any Help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my perspective, the best way to interrupt a computation is with the menu command `Evaluation/Abort Evaluation`, or from the keyboard, as described [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InterruptingCalculations.html).

However, if using `Button` is desirable for other reasons, delete `Method -> "Queued"` so that the "Stop" code is executed immediately.  Be aware, though, that `Quit[]` terminates the Kernel, losing definitions and the like; see its [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quit.html).  Instead, use `Interrupt`.  In either case , Mathematica will stop responding for several seconds, then beginning responding again.  With these changes, your code becomes

```
Grid[{{Button["Start", {i = 1; While[i < 10, Print[i]; Pause[1]; i++]}, 
    Method -> "Queued"]}, {Button["Stop", Interrupt[]]}}]
```

Note that `Abort[]` is ineffective in the code above.

**Addendum**

However, if the goal literally is to escape on command from a loop, like that in the test problem, `Abort[]`, `Break[]`, and a few other functions can be used, depending on the details of the loop.  For instance,

```
Dynamic[break = False]
Grid[{{Button["Start", {i = 1; While[i < 10, If[break == True, Abort[]]; Print[i]; Pause[1]; 
  i++]}, Method -> "Queued"]}, {Button["Stop", Dynamic[break = True]]}}]
```

The advantage of this approach is that Mathematica does not temporarily become unresponsive when "Stop" is clicked.  The disadvantage is that the loop terminates only where `If[break == True, Abort[]]` is encountered, although it can be located in multiple places in a large loop.  Also, `Dynamic` can be temperamental.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Happy to help.  I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.